# Render byte[] to image using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, image

I am currently reading an image from an SQL Server database as byte[]. I would like to pass the image either as a byte[] or a real image to jQuery and dynamically load it.

How and what would be the best approach to do this?

Thanks in advance. :)

**Edit:** Here's the solution:

1. Server-side / C#:
   `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);`
2. Client-side / Ajax:
   `$('#image').attr('src', "data:image/jpg;base64,"+employee.Image);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return the byte[] from the webserver with the correct content-type set, that way you should be able to set it as a source for a image tag. Should be the simplest solution.

Comment: What do you mean by the correct content-type set? FYI, I use Json.NET to return data to jQuery. Then I would just do <img src=$imagebytes /> ? Thanks.

Comment: for say jpeg, set request.contenttype ="image/jpeg", but if you just return the byte[] on a ajax request then you need to do something similar in the browser

Comment: Thank you. With yours and @Tesserex answer, we got it to work. :)

Answer (score 7):

If you must do it this way, you can insert image data directly into the src attribute using the following syntax:

```
data:image/<type>;base64,<data>
```

Replace  with the image type (jpg, png, gif) and  with your data, encoded in base 64.

However, as decyclone says, the best way to do this would be to create a separate page that only outputs your image data, and sends the appropriate content-type header. Then set the image src to point to that page.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think using *jQuery* is the right thing to do here. It's a client side thing. JavaScript, to be specific.

Usually, you create a page that writes all these bytes in array using `Response.Write()` and setting the content-type to jpeg, bmp, etc. depending on image type.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently reading an image from a `JSON` Response. I would like to pass this encoded string into the image control on `Jquery` template and load it dynamically, How and what would be the best approach to do this? Template is as follows:

```
<script id="ImageDiv" type="image/png">
    <div style="width:200px;height:150px;>
            <img src="${ImageView}" alt="" />
        </div>
</script>
```

Js file is as follows:

```
var demo = new Object();

$.each(msg.images, function (key, value) 
            {
                if (this.IsImage)
                 {
                    demo["ImageView"]="data:image/png;base64,"+this.Image;
                    $('#ImageDiv').tmpl(demo).appendTo("#Demo-Image");

                 }
            });
```

`JSON` Response is as follows:

```
msg = {"Images":[ "Description": "Image1", "Image": "encoded string of image", "IsImage": true, "MimeType": "image/png", } ]
```

less space to copy encoded string of image.